# Recovery Windows boot entry

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 16.04, windows-10, grub-efi

so I had Windows 10 in my laptop. I decided to install Ubuntu having a dual-boot system.

For some reason I thought it would solve some issues I was having (not relevant for this case) if I formated the EUFI partition (WRONG! I know).

What I did next was reinstall Grub but obviously only Ubuntu exists in the bootloader.

My question is what is the simplest solution to fix my grub adding windows 10 entry?

Both installations were done using EUFI mode.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you ARE sure that both, Windows and Ubuntu, are install under UEFI configuration, then you could try Grub customizer, it allows you to, along other stuff, change the displayed OS in Grub, it might help you, here is the link:
https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer

or i think you can find it in the software center, good luck!

Comment: The thing is since I deleted all the information inside the UEFI partition, Grub no longer can't find Windows boot entry and add it. This is my problem.

Comment: Can you boot windows from the boot manager at start up?

Comment: No. Only Ubuntu shows up.

Comment: In that case it might be possible that you deleted your windows instalation